# Передача элемента символьного массива в функцию с изменением значения

Tags: c++

Допустим есть символьный массив и функция:

```
void function(char a) {
    strcpy_s(a, "Something");
}

int main () {
    char mass[30];
    function();
    return 0;
}
```

Как мне передать символьный массив `mass[30]` в функцию, чтобы при вызове функции `function()` в массиве находилось слово `"Something"`?

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: Вам нужно в функцию передать пустой массив так, чтобы после её вызова в нём появилась строка?

Comment: @КириллМалышев мне необходимо передать в функцию function мой символьный массив mass[30]. Это делается для того, чтобы изменить его содержимое, но если я передам его как есть, изменения не сохранятся, значит надо изменять адрес, но как сделать это с символьным массивом я без понятия

Comment: @RomanMitasov да, но не факт что этот массив будет пустым, если это имеет значение

Comment: Массив передаётся в функцию по адресу. Если вы его там измените, то эти изменения и после выхода из функции будут. Только у вас сигнатура функции неправильная, нужно передавать char *a.

Comment: Google: 
c++ passing array to function

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, вам надо изменить тип параметра функции:

`function (char* a)`

или
`function (char a[])`

Потом при вызове функции передавайте массив в неё вот так:

```cpp
void function(char a[]) {
    strcpy_s(a, "Something");
}

int main () {
    char mass[30];
    function(mass);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Пояснение

Добавление к типу `*` делает этот тип указателем. Советую просто найти литературу или просто поискать в гугле про "указатели в C++".

Но если вкратце - `char a` это тип "символ", а `char* a` это тип "указатель на символ" или "адрес ячейки в памяти, в которой лежит символ".

Когда мы работаем с массивами в Си и C++, мы можем указывать вместо `char*` `char[]`. Квадратные скобки **семантически** говорят программисту, что это не просто указатель, а указатель на начало массива. Со стороны программы запись `char*` и `char[]` совершенно одинакова. Проще говоря - это синтаксический сахар для лучшей читаемости программ.

Именно поэтому, когда нужно сделать функцию, которая что-то делает с переменной или массивом снаружи (то есть пришедшем в параметре), надо всегда делать тип параметра этой функции указателем или ссылкой.

Про ссылки расписывать не буду, ищи-читай на просторах интернета.

Comment: Будет ли работать strcpy_s в таком случае?

Comment: Загляните в документацию [вот тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) и увидите, что эта функция принимает как раз `char*` тип (или `char[]`)

Comment: Написал *errno_t strcpy_s(char *restrict dest, rsize_t destsz, const char *restrict src);*, требует круглую скобку после dest

Comment: Всё, проблема решена, даже не пришлось использовать strcpy